# Why does my Chrome extension's Action Icon shown on all pages in omnibox?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I have following manifest

```
  "page_action": {
    "default_icon": {
      "19": "images/icon19.png",
      "38": "images/icon38.png"
    },
    "default_title": "Helper for soiduplaan.tallinn.ee"
  },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": [
        "http://soiduplaan.tallinn.ee/*"
      ],
```

But I see icon of my app in all pages I visit:
[image]
[image]

What do I do wrong? =\

Comment: Show how you're calling `chrome.pageAction.show`.

Comment: Em. I don't call it. Should I?
I just was thinking if I have content script for some page - that it shows the icon to make user know that there is something working in background. ... Maybe I misunderstood what is Page Action then ...

Comment: You did call it, I can see it in the source code of [your extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/helper-for-soiduplaantall/gjmnkpakepchhbakadboonmbnmbolicm).

Comment: Oh, my indeed I did. Stub code. Forgot about it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your current code is:

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(a) {
    chrome.pageAction.show(a);
});
```

This causes the page action to be shown whenever a page is loaded, ie for every tab.
If you want to restrict the page action to certain pages only, check the `tab.url` property:

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
    if (tab.url && tab.url.indexOf('http://soiduplaan.tallinn.ee/') === 0) {
        chrome.pageAction.show(tabId);
    }
});
```

For more info, read the docs for [`chrome.tabs.onUpdated`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs.html#event-onUpdated).

Comment: Note: The `tabs.onUpdated` event is not the most efficient way of showing the pageAction on some pages. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20855956/how-to-show-chrome-extension-on-certain-domains/20856789#20856789) for a better method using the `webNavigation` API.