# How to show Chrome Extension on certain domains?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm writing my first Chrome Extension. I've used permission, but I'm seeing my button everywhere.

How can I only show the button on the addresses I'm writing the extension for?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Although the [answer from @Sorter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20856089/1097600) works, it is not the best way to solve the problem.

First and foremost, it does not *always* work. If the page used `history.pushState`, the page action will disappear and not come back until you trigger the `onUpdated` or `onHighlighted` event again <sup>[Chromium issue 231075](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=231075)</sup>.

Secondly, the method is inefficient, because it's triggered for every update of tab state *on all pages*.

The most efficient and reliable way to get a page action to appear on certain domains is to use the [`declarativeContent`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/declarativeContent) API. This is only available since Chrome 33. Before that, the [`webNavigation`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webNavigation.html) API was the most suitable API. The advantage of these API over the method using the `tabs` API is that you can safely use [event pages](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/event_pages.html), because you can declare [URL filters](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/events.html#type-UrlFilter). With these URL filters, the events will only be triggered if you navigate to a page that matches the URL filters. Consequently, your extension/event page will not be activated until really needed (= no wasted RAM or CPU).

Here's a minimal example (`background.js`) using the `webNavigation` API:

```js
function onWebNav(details) {
    if (details.frameId === 0) {
        // Top-level frame
        chrome.pageAction.show(details.tabId);
    }
}
var filter = {
    url: [{
        hostEquals: 'example.com'
    }]
};
chrome.webNavigation.onCommitted.addListener(onWebNav, filter);
chrome.webNavigation.onHistoryStateUpdated.addListener(onWebNav, filter);
```

`manifest.json`:

```js
{
    "name": "Name ",
    "version": "1",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "background": {
        "scripts": ["background.js"],
        "persistent": false
    },
    "page_action": {
        "default_title": "Only visible on stackoverflow.com"
    },
    "permissions": [
        "webNavigation"
    ]
}
```

If you target Chrome 33 and higher, then you can also use the declarativeContent API instead. Simply replace the "webNavigation" permission with "declarativeContent", and use the following background script (background.js):

```js
chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(function() {
    chrome.declarativeContent.onPageChanged.removeRules(undefined, function() {
        chrome.declarativeContent.onPageChanged.addRules([{
            conditions: [
                new chrome.declarativeContent.PageStateMatcher({
                    pageUrl: {
                        hostEquals: 'example.com'
                    }
                })
            ],
            actions: [new chrome.declarativeContent.ShowPageAction()]
        }]);
    });
});
```

In both examples, I used a [UrlFilter](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/events#type-UrlFilter) that matches the `example.com` domain.

Comment: Unfortunately it does not work for me. Not sure why. My chrome version is 41.xxxx and I have added webNavigation permission in my background script. But still it does not hide the extension on the page. I have tried both of the methods you suggested :(

Comment: @rahulserver Did you reload the extension (not just the background script) after adding the new permissions?

Comment: Yes. I reloaded the extension form More Tools-> Extensions. Also reloaded the web page. Also restarted chrome. Still same result.

Comment: @rahulserver I cannot help you any further without seeing the code.

Comment: Would you want me to post a new question? or shall I upload the code somewhere and give you the url of the code?

Comment: @rahulserver If you think that the answer will benefit the community, then by all means post a new question.

Comment: ok will post a new question in some time. I would share the link to that question in this comment.

Comment: @RobW I'm experimenting with this API and would like to ask, is there a way to match **array of url's** in *hostEquals*?

Comment: @WolfWar Create multiple `chrome.declarativeContent.PageStateMatcher`s, one for every host. e.g. `var conditions = ['example.com', 'example.org'].map(function(host){ return new chrome.declarativeContent.PageStateMatcher({pageUrl: {hostEquals: host}}); }); // Now use conditions in the ruleset.`

Comment: will this work if I don't know url's and length of array?...it can be random sites

Comment: @WolfWar Yes. The example given in my comment is generic and can be used for arrays of any length.

Answer (score 5):

Create background.js which checks for updated and highlighted tab.

```
function checkForValidUrl(tabId, changeInfo, tab) {

   // If  'example.com' is the hostname for the tabs url.
   var a = document.createElement ('a');
   a.href = tab.url;
   if (a.hostname == "example.com") {
       // ... show the page action.
       chrome.pageAction.show(tabId);
   }
};

// Listen for any changes to the URL of any tab.
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(checkForValidUrl);
//For highlighted tab as well
chrome.tabs.onHighlighted.addListener(checkForValidUrl);
```

Create popup.html and popup.js in the similar manner.

*You can use the variables defined in background.js in content scripts (popup.js) with*
`chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage().variableName`

Here's the [example extention download link](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/examples/api/pageAction/pageaction_by_url.zip).

For your reference and ease, here's the sample manifest.json file

```
 {
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "Example Extension",
    "version": "1.0",

    "background": {
        "scripts": ["background.js"]
    },

    "page_action":{
        "default_icon": "images/icon_16.png",
        "default_popup": "popup.html",
        "default_title": "Title for the extension"
    },
    "permissions": [
        "tabs"
    ]
}
```

Comment: How would I implement this? In a background script?

Comment: You should create two files. background.html and background.js. include js file in html file and paste the above code in js file. Let know me, if its not working.

Comment: I'm getting a `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'onUpdated' of undefined ` in my console :(

Comment: Is probably the    "tabs" permission :P

Comment: @KeesC.Bakker No, it's not. The `tabs` API is always available. You've probably put the code in a content script, while the API is only available in an extension page (e.g. [background page](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/background_pages.html)).

Comment: I had a `browser_action` instead of a `page_action`. So the button is now hidden. But also on pages with a 'g' hahah.

Comment: BAM! It works. Were the permissions, I had a double object in my manifest. The `background` permission is not really needed right?

Comment: Try removing and see 3:)

Comment: The first argument in a onHighlighted callback is not the tabId. The example should have separate callback functions.

Answer (score 1):

An Updated Way:

I use the following with great success:

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, info, tab) {
    var url = info.url || tab.url;
    if(url && url.indexOf('example.com') > -1)
        chrome.pageAction.show(tabId);
    else
        chrome.pageAction.hide(tabId);
});
```

Comment: Note that this fires an event every single time *any* tab in a user's browser is updated. @Rob W's answer using the declarativeContent API is less resource intensive.