# Why doesn't this URL scheme match my URL?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, url-scheme

I was [filtering URLs](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/events#type-UrlFilter) for pageAction with `hostSuffix` according to this SO answer: [How to show Chrome Extension on certain domains?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20856789/322020)

```
var onWebNav = function(details){ if (details.frameId === 0) chrome.pageAction.show(details.tabId); };
var filter = { url: [{ hostSuffix: "reddit.com" }] };
chrome.webNavigation.onCommitted.addListener(onWebNav, filter);
chrome.webNavigation.onHistoryStateUpdated.addListener(onWebNav, filter);
```

But if I want a pattern, like `http://*.reddit.com/r/*/comments/*`, I should use `schemes` instead of `hostSuffix`, right? According to https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/match_patterns this should match everything:

```
var filter = { url: [{ schemes: ["http://*/*"] }] };
```

but it doesn't match even this URL `http://www.reddit.com/r/IAmA/comments/z1c9z/`.

Do I use `schemes` filter in wrong way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that is a valid scheme. A scheme is what identifies the protocol used, it shouldn't have any wildcards.

The [match_patterns](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/match_patterns) link describes a fully build up pattern, consisting of 3 parts, including a scheme. This is a different system from the one you're trying to use, which is based on [matching different parts of an URL separately](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/events#type-UrlFilter). The patterns link does give you info on valid schemes, in the basic syntax table:

```
<scheme> := '*' | 'http' | 'https' | 'file' | 'ftp'
```

Try `var filter = { url: [{ schemes: ["http"] }] };` instead. This should match any URL that goes over plain old HTTP.

To achieve your desired matching, the best thing would be to use either the `originAndPathMatches` or `urlMatches` filters, since you need the regular expression for matching the host and the specific syntax of the path.

Comment: So `urlMatches` is the best approach available? `{ url: [{ urlMatches: "^http://[^.]+\\.reddit\\.com/r/[^/]+/comments/" }] }`

Comment: @Nakilon Ah, sorry, I got so fixated on the schemes part that I forgot your original goal >_< I'd go for `originAndPathMatches`, since you don't need to match anything aside that, but yeah, those regular expression ones would be the way to go.

Comment: No problem. Now at least I know that `schemes` isn't the same as `Match Patterns`.

Comment: @Nakilon Glad I could help. Good luck with your extension.