# Hide pageAction with declarativeContent in Google Chrome extension API

Tags: javascript, regex, google-chrome-extension

This is my first experience with making a Chrome extension and I am not too experienced with JS, to be honest.

- I want to use `persistent: false`, `declarativeContent` and `pageStateMatcher` API calls and permissions instead of tabs and/or full on raw JS if that is an option at all.
- I need to show `pageAction` icon when URL consists of anything other than a 2nd-level domain with exception for exotics like co.uk:

  ☐google.com — 2lvl domain
  ☐bbc.co.uk — exotic 3lvl domain equivalent to a 2lvl domain
  ☑images.google.com — 3lvl domain
  ☑google.com/search — 2lvl domain with path
  ☑news.bbc.co.uk — exotic 4lvl domain equivalent to a 3lvl domain
  ☑bbc.co.uk/article — exotic 3lvl domain with path equivalent to a 2lvl domain with path
- I need to hide `pageAction` for the opposite of the condition above.
- I need the action performed by clicking on the `pageAction` to be updating URL by trimming it of anything other than a 2nd-level domain.

I am only yet working at the detection part, planning to add URL updating functionality after I'm done with this part.

**manifest.json**

```
{
  // Required
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Website Home Button",
  "version": "0.1",

  // Recommended
  "description": "Icon made by Freepik from www.flaticon.com is licensed by CC BY 3.0",
  "icons": {
    "48": "icon48.png",
    "128": "icon128.png"
  },
  // PageAction
  "page_action": {
    "default_icon": {
      "19": "icon19.png",
      "38": "icon38.png"
    },
    "default_title": "Website Home Button" //Tooltip
  },

  // Optional
  "author": "Murad 'Erquint' Beybalaev",
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"],
    // Recommended
    "persistent": false
  },
  "minimum_chrome_version": "18",
  "permissions": ["declarativeContent"]
}
```

**background.js**

```
// Update the declarative rules on install or upgrade.
chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(function() {
  chrome.declarativeContent.onPageChanged.addRules([{
    conditions: [
      // URL is not a 2lvl domain...
      new chrome.declarativeContent.PageStateMatcher(
        {
          pageUrl: {urlMatches: "[^.]+?\..+?(\.|\/).*"}
        }
      ),
      //Hostname is not a 3lvl .uk domain
      !(new chrome.declarativeContent.PageStateMatcher(
        {
          pageUrl: {hostSuffix: ".uk"}
        }
      ))],
    // ... show the page action.
    actions: [new chrome.declarativeContent.ShowPageAction() ]
  }]);
});

//[^.]+?\..+?(\.(?!uk)|\/).*
//(?<=\.)(.+?\..+)
```

At the bottom you can see the regular expressions I was going to use for detection and trimming but `pageStateMatcher` uses RE2 for regular expressions and it doesn't support lookarounds (the whole API feels counter-productive to me) so I decided to use `hostSuffix` condition in conjunction but for the love of God I cannot understand how to work with these conditions.

If to follow RE2 constrains, I need the logic to be (pseudocode)

```
if(
//URL contains more than just a 2nd-level domain
urlMatchRegExp("[^.]+?\..+?(\.|\/).*")
//AND URL isn't an exotic .uk 3rd-level domain.
&& !urlMatchRegExp("([^.]+?\.){2}uk"))
  {pageAction.show}
else
  {pageAction.hide}
```

How do I nest/**&&** conditions?
How do I **!** conditions?
Conditions nor events seem to not be boolean so the logic operators don't seem to work on them.
Should I ditch the API and use JS RegExp?
Can I update the URL without tabs premission?

I'm at a loss.
Any guidance would be much appreciated.

**P.S.**
I just tried using this ruleset with more powerful RegExp but still w/o lookarounds:

```
[{
    conditions: [
      //URL is not a 2lvl domain...
      new chrome.declarativeContent.PageStateMatcher(
        {
          pageUrl: {urlMatches: "^[^.]+?\..+?(\.[^uk]|\/).*$"}
        }
      )],
    // ... show the page action.
    actions: [new chrome.declarativeContent.ShowPageAction() ]
  },{
    conditions: [
      //URL is not a 2lvl domain...
      new chrome.declarativeContent.PageStateMatcher(
        {
          pageUrl: {urlMatches: "^[^.]+?\.[^\.|\/]+?(\.uk)??$"}
        }
      )],
    // ... show the page action.
    actions: [new chrome.declarativeContent.HidePageAction() ]
  }]
```

But turns out there's no `chrome.declarativeContent.HidePageAction()`.

Is it supposed to hide automagically when the conditions are not met?
Let's try.
Well it doesn't.
I'm trying the above w/o the hide rule and it shows on either

```
example.com
www.example.com
example.com/index.html
www.example.com/index.html
```

regardless.
It's just permanently everywhere.
No errors in debugging though w/o the hide rule.

**P.P.S.**
Kinda rewrote the whole thing following a template by Google:
**background.js**

```
chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(function() {
  chrome.declarativeContent.onPageChanged.removeRules(undefined, function() {
    chrome.declarativeContent.onPageChanged.addRules([
      {
        conditions: [
          new chrome.declarativeContent.PageStateMatcher({
            pageUrl:  {urlMatches: "^[^.]+?\..+?(\.[^uk]|\/).*$"},
          })
        ],
        actions: [ new chrome.declarativeContent.ShowPageAction() ]
      }
    ]);
  });
});
```

Still getting every possible false-positive.

**P.P.P.S.**
RE2 sucks so much!
I'm gonna try `tabs` with more JS.

Comment: I'd say it's more of a regex question than anything. As in, "build a single RE2-regex that does it". I don't see at a glance why you need lookarounds..

Comment: @Xan Take a look at P.P.S. It's a lookaround-less regexp accepted by RE2 with no exceptions thrown. The problem is that the icon doesn't hide when the condition is not met.

Comment: That said, you have [a bigger problem](https://publicsuffix.org/list/) on your hands than `.co.uk`.

Comment: @Xan Yeah, I know there are more "exotics" as I call them. It's a matter of order to deal with them after the main functionality is in place.

Comment: The "exotics" list is literally thousands of entries long. Doing it with a regex looks counterproductive. Maybe you should abandon `declarativeContent` and do it _ye olde_ way with `tabs` events. Basically, the API was not designed to implement complex logic (since the checks don't run in scripted environment but natively)

Comment: @Xan May as well be but I'm afraid I might encounter even more problems due to my little experience. For now I want to understand why does the icon appear on the tabs with non-matching url. It goes against the documentation or what I understand it as at https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/declarativeContent#type-PageStateMatcher.

Comment: Because the path is _never_ empty, it's at least `/`. Your regexp fails `http://example.com` but matches `http://example.com/`

Comment: @Xan I added a / in the end of regex ("^[^.]+?\..+?(\.[^uk]|\/).*\/$") which seems to work around this issue in my desktop evaluator. Now in browser it still show an icon on everything **except** `example.com/index.php` but shows if I add a / in the end of that URL.

Comment: @Xan I even tried as simple of an expression as `.*\..*\..*` (if URL contains 2 dots) and it still doesn't work even though it works if I do `/.*\..*\..*/.test(document.URL)` in JS on page through console.

Answer (score 2):

RE2 proven to be a dysfunctional disaster.
Some of Chrome APIs turned out to be counter-productive abominations.

Using `tabs` premissions alowed more JS flexibility and in comparison to pure API(+RE2) it actually worked.
Lookarounds were dealt with anyway — they're a powerful supplementary to "regular" regular expressions but with great power comes great responsibility.
The basic extension capabilities are in place.
"Exotic" domain names and some eyecandy tweaks are planned.

Thanks to @Xan for the information and advice he provided.
If anyone is curious about this tiny project — you can check it out at https://bitbucket.org/Erquint/website_home_button_extension_for_chrome

Comment: Do not use the tabs API, the webNavigation API is more suitable for toggling page actions. For the pros and cons of your approach (tabs), webNavigation and declarativeContent, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20855956/how-to-show-chrome-extension-on-certain-domains. What you're seeking in the declarativeContent API is currently not possible, because there is no way to negate conditions or actions. I have created a feature request for that at https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=494509, you can star it to follow the progress of the issue.