# Chrome Extension - How do trigger the extension only in specific URL

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I have created a google extension that calls my API to get if there is new cookies added to the API and that API would then transfer it into my chrome browser. E.g.

[image]

The problem is that whatever site I actually try to access, it does quite alot calls to my API which I am scared of where it will could eventually overload the database and my manifest.json looks like this:

```
{
    "name": "Cookie Injector",
    "version": "0.1",
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "background": {
        "service_worker": "./js/background.js"
    },
    "permissions": ["cookies", "storage", "tabs"],
    "action": {
        "default_popup": "./html/popup.html"
    },
    "host_permissions": ["<all_urls>"],
    "icons": {
        "16": "/images/icon.png",
        "32": "/images/icon.png",
        "48": "/images/icon.png",
        "128": "/images/icon.png"
    }
}
```

and my background.js is:

```
function get_pending_cookies(discord_id) {
  const id = new URLSearchParams({ 'user_id': discord_id });
  return fetch(`http://cookie.pynewbie.com/pending-cookies?${id}`, {
    method: 'GET',
  }).then((response) => {
    return response.json();
  }).then((json) => {
    return json;
  });
}

function handle_cookies(discord_id) {
  get_pending_cookies(discord_id).then((result) => {
    ...

      // detect is focused on correct page
      chrome.tabs.query({ currentWindow: true, active: true }, function (tabs) {
        // getting current tab's URL
        if (!(tabs === undefined || tabs.length === 0)) {
          if (tabs[0].url === url) {
            console.log("USER OPENED CORRECT PAGE, RELOADING");
            chrome.tabs.reload(tabs[0].id);
          }
        }
      });
    })
  });
}


chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
  function (request, sender, sendResponse) {
    sendResponse(request);
    set_discord_id(request.discord_id);
  }
);

chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(() => {
  handle_cookies;
});
```

My question is how can I make the API (`get_pending_cookies`) to only be called when I enter specific URL e.g. pythonewbie.com (then it should do the API calls otherwise skip)

Comment: Instead of tabs.onUpdated use webNavigation.onCommitted with url filter as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20856789). Also `handle_cookies;` should be `handle_cookies();`

Comment: @wOxxOm By checking the examle, im not quite sure how I can apply this in my code, is there any chance you should show an example?

Comment: Copy the first code block except onHistoryStateUpdated line and put your old code from onUpdated into onWebNav.

Comment: @wOxxOm That seemed to work ! :D Thank you so much!