# How do I make an extension icon disappear from irrelevant pages?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

My extension works for a single web site. I want its icon to be removed from the Chrome taskbar, when the user is not visiting that specific page.

I tried to use solutions that are present in these questions:

[Why does my Chrome extension's Action Icon shown on all pages in omnibox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16855910/why-does-my-chrome-extensions-action-icon-shown-on-all-pages-in-omnibox)

[How to show Chrome Extension on certain domains?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20855956/how-to-show-chrome-extension-on-certain-domains/20856789#20856789)

But none of the accepted answers work for me and I can't understand why. Is this because I have my extension launched in developer mode? How can I solve this problem? Please, help!

Comment: You cant. Because Google.

Comment: Is this a recent change? Because in those questions people are suggesting solutions to this problem

Comment: It's a change that's only a few weeks old.  The official documentation also hasn't caught up yet (in the examples or the api) last I looked.